# Is there a way to read SNS published message via Django framework instead of AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-sns

Trying to read the message from SNS topic which is created in AWS instance. Unable to get the info other than lambda function. If we use HTTP end point how does it works for other ARN ?

We are using Django rest framework. So wanted to read message from SNS as soon as message publish to respective topic

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscribe-https-s-endpoints-to-topic.html

Comment: Sure let me go through the above document

Answer (score 1):

SNS is a `push` service, you can't `pull` directly from it. In order to read messages that were sent to an SNS topic you need to route these messages to an endpoint (via creating a subscription to the endpoint). If you have an HTTP server that can listen to these requests, then [read more here about how to use the HTTP subscription of SNS.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html)

The most common approach is to route the messages to an SQS Queue by using an SQS endpoint - that way you can `pull` messages at your own pace without worrying about sudden bursts of messages causing issues with your HTTP server or your lambda concurrency suddenly being too expensive.
[Read more here about fanning out to an SQS Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Will check and come back on the link which you have shared